# Mysql Workbench and polish language input from jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, character-encoding

I have got problem while inserting some data in polish language(characters like ąćęłóżź) into table. I'm getting some strange chars in table's. In `jsp` files I have set page coding to utf 8.
Mysql worbench `character-set-server` set to `utf8` and database collation to `utf8_polish_ci`.
I have also set windows enviroment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly descriptive as to which "strange chars" you're seeing, but I'll assume that you actually mean [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) such as `ÄÄÄÅÃ³Å¼Åº` instead of `ąćęłóżź` and thus not question marks such as `???????` instead of `ąćęłóżź`.

You need to invoke `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` *before* you collect POST request parameters by `request.getParameter(name)`, otherwise the server platform default one will be used to decode them from the query string, which is often ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8.

The best place to set the request character encoding is a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped on an URL pattern covering all POST requests.

#### See also

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: for example I get "ÅcieÅ¼kowo" instead of Ścieżkowo

Comment: This indeed confirms that ISO-8859-1 is been used to decode the parameter.

Comment: I've put this in web.xml
`<web-app>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>`
but this request line solved my problem. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. This only sets the response encoding, not the request encoding. You should keep it! Check the "See also" link for detailed background information.